# UWP Binding two booleans to IsEnabled property

Tags: c#, uwp, binding, boolean

I have two different objects instantiated in my UWP program. Their class definitions look like this:

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class FirstClass : INotifiyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isEnabled = false;
        public bool IsEnabled 
        {
            get => isEnabled;
            set
            {
                isEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public class SecondClass : INotifiyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isEnabled = false;
        public bool IsEnabled 
        {
            get => isEnabled;
            set
            {
                isEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The binding on the XAML side currently  looks like this:

```
<Button Content="Press me if you can" IsEnabled="{x:Bind FirstClass.IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

With this code, Button.IsEnabled is only dependent on FirstClass.IsEnabled, what I'd like to achieve is for the Button.IsEnabled property to be dependent on FirstClass.IsEnabled AND SecondClass.IsEnabled. How can I obtain such a result?

I wanted to implement MultiBinding, but it seems to be a WPF-only feature

Answer (score 1):

We can't bind two properties directly in xaml.It seems to only be able to operate in **code-behind**.When you set the IsEnabled of FirstClass or SecondClass,then judge the IsEnabled of Button manually.

Comment: Is it possible to bind two code-behing variables? Like, creating a third class which has two separeted bindings to FirstClass and SecondClass which will be used as source and an output which would be what the xaml behind to.

Comment: It is feasible to combine the two isEnabled properties to determine and output only one value, ensuring that the bound value is unique.